# Distribute Java 8 JRE without installation?

Tags: java

Our IT policies are holding back my development efforts and we are still on Java 6. I have decided I am not going to wait anymore and move my internal customers to Java 8, so I can start improving my applications with lambdas and better code.

However they do not have admin rights over their Windows machines. Is there a way I can distribute a binary or non-installation version of Java, and invoke it with a shell/batch file with my JARs?

Comment: Yes. Either copy the JRE from an existing installation or download the `tar.gz` archives from Oracle and unzip them: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Comment: You can embed the JRE within your application (essentially).  This will involve having an already installed version the JRE.  Basically, you copy the JRE installation directory over to a directory within your application (we use `jre` funny enough).  You then point your startup scripts/batch files/exes to point to this JRE instead...

Comment: **"I have decided I am not going to wait anymore and move my internal customers to Java 8"** this statement is quite energetic and full of hope,  I can feel that for you,, :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a_horse_with_no_name and MadProgrammer, this worked very well and production has worked great with this setup. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html